# How to stop a simple Discord bot from pinging users?

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm creating a simple Discord call-and-response bot. Every time it responds to a user, it pings that user. How can I stop it from pinging users, while still retaining all other functions?

I've attached an example of what I'm trying to get rid of (how would I get the bot to just respond with "k" instead of "@[user], k"?). 
I have very little knowledge of Javascript or programming in general, so I'm not sure where to start. 
I'm using a Macbook Air with Mojave 10.14.4, doing my coding with Terminal and Sublime Text. If that's relevant. 
Base code comes from [this guide](https://medium.com/davao-js/2019-tutorial-creating-your-first-simple-discord-bot-47fc836a170b).

Here's the call-and-response code from the bot.js file.

```
client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.author == client.user) {
        return
    }
  msg.reply('k');
});
```

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ul1TN.png) an example of what I'm trying to get rid of - I don't want the bot to ping users when it responds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`msg.reply()` replies directly back to a user given the message, hence the bot tagging the user. If you don't want this reply feature, you can instead use `msg.channel.send()`